# What can lock the only MySQL db process?

Tags: mysql, blocking

A plain old "delete single record" statement froze on me. Suspecting a (dead)lock issue, I checked the process list to see what blocks the `delete`. The `delete` statement was the only running db process and still its state was `Locked`. It remained in this state for something like 2 minutes and then finished successfully.

Question: what can make a MySQL process `Locked` except another process holding a lock?

Below is the output from `show processlist`:

```
mysql> show processlist;
+-------+------+-----------------------------------+------+---------+------+--------+---------------------------------------------+
| Id    | User | Host                              | db   | Command | Time | State  | Info                                        |
+-------+------+-----------------------------------+------+---------+------+--------+---------------------------------------------+
| 79616 | htt  | gateway1.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:42254 | foo  | Query   |  106 | Locked | delete from xbarApp_testfoo where id = 2279 |
| 79618 | htt  | gateway1.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:41009 | foo  | Query   |    0 | NULL   | show processlist                            |
+-------+------+-----------------------------------+------+---------+------+--------+---------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.35 sec)
```

Comment: Does your server still have free disk space?

Comment: I do not think it means what you think it means.

Comment: @JannePikkarainen Yup, there are a couple dozen gigabytes free.

Comment: @TomO'Connor You mean it includes "waiting for system resources" and not only locks held by other processes?

Comment: if the 2min sound awfully long - check your indices. either id is not indexed, or too many things are indexed and delete will break a sweat constantly rebuilding indices if there are many things with id=2279 (usually "id" would be assumed to be a unique surrogate primary key by convention, but I am not in an assuming mood today :) . If nothing helps - strace it and look at what it is actually doing.

Comment: @rackandboneman Id was primary. Also, would the process show as "Locked" during the time spent fetching the index?